# Dynamic CRM 2011. Hide/show tabs using radio buttons issue

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I have this code that hides tabs and shows tabs in CRM 2011. By default all tabs are hidden, but when the client has the product purchased (yes selected), the tab is showen.

The issue I am having is when I click yes and save & close. Then reopen the account, the tab is hidden, but the option is still yes.

The code is:
`function showTab(tabNumber, optionField, optionValue) {
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute(optionField).getValue() == optionValue) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabNumber).setVisible(true);
    }
    else {
        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(tabNumber).setVisible(false);
    }
}`

The option I have is:
 2,"new_server",'1'

I got the code from this place:
[Show a Tab Dynamics CRM 2011](http://www.magnetismsolutions.co.nz/blog/11-06-28/Show_a_Tab_Based_on_a_Radio_Button_Dynamics_CRM_2011.aspx)

I am still working on this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register this function on both the form's OnLoad event and the field's OnChange event. It sounds, from your description, that it is registered and working for the OnChange event but the OnLoad event.

Comment: The field properties for the product purchased doesn't have a OnLoad event. I do see the forum properties to have the onLoad. I am a little fuzzy on how to get that to work.

Comment: You need to have the JavaScript when the form is loaded and when the field is changed. It is two different events. One, the OnLoad, is at the form level and the other, OnChange, is at the field level.

Comment: That would be correct, it is the exact same function call and parameters as the OnChange. This is specifically stated in the post to which you linked in your question: _That’s all you need to set for this, you can now Save and Close the Web Resource. Next you will need to open the Form, to call this function from the ‘Is Student’ onChange, **and from the Forms onLoad events**._

Answer (score 0):

You currently have the function registered on the onChange event for the radio button control.

Additionally, you need to register an onLoad event for the form.

1. Create a new web resource.
2. Open Form Properties.
3. Add form to available resources.
4. Add event handler onLoad, and call your webresource.

In the web resource you can just have a call to your showTab function.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the form for customization, look at the top ribbon of the form. You will see Form Properties icon right next to Preview. Click on Form Properties and then add the JavaScript web resource in the Form Library.

Choose Event: OnLoad from the drop down and then click add under the Event Handler. 
Choose the web resource of your choice, add the function name being used in your code (showTab).

This will add the function to your Onload event of the form.

Comment: I want the parameters to be empty correct? So I did this, but when I save and close the Account the option is selected correctly, but the form is still hiding the tab.